# Batch scripting find the first occurence of string taskid

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have a text file with a string occurs multiple lines. I want to get the line where this is the first occurrence of the string. I could find all occurrences using below command but I want only first occurrence in single line command.

```
findstr /C:"taskId" Book.txt
```

Book.txt

```
3047 [main] INFO  com.informatica.saas.utilities.task.ICSTask  -
Submitted run of the task: taskId=0015FL0Z0000000000R6,
taskRunId=20869
https://use4.dm-us.informaticacloud.com/saas/api/v2/activity/activityMonitor
https://use4.dm-us.informaticacloud.com/saas/api/v2/activity/activityMonitor
https://use4.dm-us.informaticacloud.com/saas/api/v2/activity/activityLog?taskId=0015FL0Z0000000000R6&runId=20869
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /C:"taskId" Book.txt') do (
   echo %%a
   goto :continue
)
:continue
```

Comment: :Could you please explain how this works. This works independently but doesnt work as part of my script, where I have other functionality implemented on this

Comment: what does :continue do ?

Comment: `goto :continue` breaks the loop so it is iterating once only...

Comment: What is the rest of your script?